# Make zkbd ignore $DISPLAY

Tags: shell, zsh

Is it possible to make zkbd ignore `$DISPLAY` variable? I have set up when I log in to different X sessions and it is annoying if suddenly I need to reenter/copy configuration (and I have no idea why `$DISPLAY` could affect keyboard settings).